# How do I get a list of users where latest status is True?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Take this users and status list:

[image]

I need an SQL that will give me a list of users where the latest status is True - that will be users: 2 and 5 (user 4 latest status is False)

How can archive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: Personally, I like the cross apply approach.  but as with everything; it depends on your environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451972/cross-apply-select-top-1-much-slower-than-row-number

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. How do you determine the "latest" `Status` when all of the columns are datatype `pixel`? What results do you expect from the sample data? What have you tried? Your actual question is quite perplexing: "How can archive this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and then filter on status is true:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY StatusDate DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT UserID
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND Status = 'True';
```